# Contacts-like list headers behaviour in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm trying to achive the same effect for group headers as in contacts list in wp7 for "a" "b" "c" ... headers.

[image]

I've used LongListSelector with a group template, but i need a first group header stay at the top of the list, untill it will be pushed out by next header while scrolling.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Quick Jump Grid: http://blogs.claritycon.com/blog/2010/10/06/wp7-quick-jump-grid-sample-code/

If you have Adam Nathan's book, his sample app Cocktails uses a control like that too - but he implements his own.